# Como utilizar a função de agregação SUM em uma consulta NHIBERNATE?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Minha consulta consiste em saber o `NumCarroId`, `TotalGasto` e `VlrUnit`, em  `Sql` eu consegui fazer isso mas quando jogo na `HQL` retorna o seguinte erro:

Aplicação do `GROUP BY` junto ao `SUM` para fazer um ToList, para me mostra uma lista ja somada, porém consta muito erros

Pessoal se alguem pode ajuda, por enquanto não encontrei nenhuma resposta que desse certo

Erro que retorna:

> string hql = "select a.NumCarro.Id, sum(a.TotalGasto) gastos from Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido Between :dataInicial AND :dataFinal GROUP BY a.NumCarro.Id";

## Código

```
public IList<Abastecimento> Resumo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal)
{
    string hql = "SELECT NumCarroId, DtAbastecido FROM Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido Between :dataInicial AND :dataFinal GROUP BY a.NumCarroId";
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
    .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
    .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal);
    return query.List<Abastecimento>();
}
```

## Tabela Abastecimento

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Abastecimento] (
    [Id]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DtAbastecido]  DATETIME        NULL,
    [Litro]         INT             NULL,
    [VlrUnit]       DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [TotalGasto]    DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
    [AutorId]       INT             NULL,
    [NumCarroId]    INT             NULL,
    [Km]            INT             NULL,
    [NomeProdutoId] INT             NULL,
    [Km_Andado]     INT             NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK84286500787E6DCB] FOREIGN KEY ([AutorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Usuario] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK842865002F58EAD8] FOREIGN KEY ([NumCarroId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Veiculo] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK8428650023D2F9D9] FOREIGN KEY ([NomeProdutoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Compra] ([Id])
);
```

## Model Abastecimento

```
 public class Abastecimento {
 public virtual int Id {
  get;
  set;
 }
 [Required]
 public virtual int Litro {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual DateTime ? DtAbastecido {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual decimal VlrUnit {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual int Km {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual decimal TotalGasto {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual int Km_Andado {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Usuario Autor {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Compra NomeProduto {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Veiculo NumCarro {
  get;
  set;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Pelo teste que estava fazendo no sql, fazendo assim ele trazia os carro que eu precisava e no periodo, usei o sum para pode fazer a soma, so nao coloquei ali na consulta porque estava dando um erro gigantesco

Comment: Se for isso guilherme: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d405/1

Comment: Isso marconi é isso que eu quero, mas como seria para aplica isso no c#,

Comment: Guilherme Gera algum erro no C#? Ou não retorna nada?

Comment: são dois erros que acontecem é o que coloquei e se eu tenta implementar o sum é um que irei coloca ali na pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71825/discussion-between-marconi-and-guilherme-padovam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloquei essa seguinte linha de codigo no controller, e consegui acrescentar o Group By, porém ainda não consigo fazer o SUM

```
var teste = consulta.Where(i => i.DtAbastecido >= dataInicio && i.DtAbastecido <= dataFinal)
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.NumCarro.NCarro})
                    .Select(x => x.First())
                    .OrderBy(x => x.NumCarro.NCarro);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pelo seu erro, essa pergunta: [How to resolve No data type for node error in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974121/how-to-resolve-no-data-type-for-node-error-in-hibernate), diz:

Uma Query HQL deve conter as propriedades do objeto e não os campos da estrutura da sua tabela.

No SQL:

```
select numCarroId, sum(valorGasto) gastos from Abastecimento
where dataAbastecimento between '2017-05-21' and '2017-11-13'
group by numCarroId
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d405/1)

Você me passou via chat o **Model Abastecimento** assim:

```
public class Abastecimento {
 public virtual int Id {
  get;
  set;
 }
 [Required]
 public virtual int Litro {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual DateTime ? DtAbastecido {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual decimal VlrUnit {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual int Km {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual decimal TotalGasto {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual int Km_Andado {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Usuario Autor {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Compra NomeProduto {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public virtual Veiculo NumCarro {
  get;
  set;
 }
}
}
```

Modifique seu HQL para:

```
    public IList < Abastecimento > Resumo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFinal) {
  string hql = "select a.NumCarro.Id, sum(a.TotalGasto) gastos from Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecido Between :dataInicial AND :dataFinal GROUP BY a.NumCarro.Id";
  IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
   .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
   .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal);
  return query.List < Abastecimento > ();
 }
```

Comment: Respondi a pergunta baseada no erro, minha intenção é que o OP entenda um pouco do problema. Se alguém conhecer de `NHibernate` e poder contribuir eu removo minha resposta.

Comment: O chat tem bastante informações: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71825/discussion-between-marconi-and-guilherme-padovam

Comment: a principio o NHibernate esta certo... mas eu não usaria esse ORM... é muito lento

Comment: Qual seria um ORM melhor?

Comment: o Entity Framework já é melhor, mas se você precisar de performance use o Dapper. Que no seu caso seria bem melhor já que você não usar linq.... o Dapper cairia bem.

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam, Qual erro ao executar o hql dessa resposta? Erro não seria no parse de retorno do List? Pois como o ORM saberá a qual propriedade `sum(a.TotalGasto) gastos` se refere para o retorno?

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam, olhe como foi implementado essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884363/2290538

Comment: Vou olhar e se consegui coloca a resposta

Comment: @FernandoLeal boa analisada, creio que minha resposta falta algum detalhe.